# How does chatgpt interpret prompts?

Tags: chatgpt, open-ai, chat-bots, natural-language-understanding

First of all, my English isn't very good, please bear with me.

I've heard that chatgpt is a decoder-only model, which doesn't use any encoder model.
How does it interpret our prompts if it doesn't use any encoder model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChatGPT is the finetuning of GPT_3.5, which is a decoder-only model. It does not interpret the prompt the same way the encode-decoder model does. It is using autoregressive pre-training, which generates text based on the input.

You Provide a prompt to ChatGPT. It can be any text like a question, statement, or text.

Your Prompt is broken into a series of tokens. every token is a word or part of a word.

Each token is transformed into the contextual embedding which is a vector representation of the token. This holds the contextual meaning of the token with respect to surrounding tokens.

The main Decoding process then processes the decoder part of the model. The decode only generates one token at a time and uses previously generated tokens as well as the prompt as context. This process is done in an autoregressive manner.

The final output is a sequence of tokens that need to be converted back to the text.

This is the complete decoding process. Hope you understood.